# Azure storage tables customer tables

Tags: azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I would like to ask some advise if this is a bad practice or not.

I'm having few tables where I store data about customers and then one table where there is customer specific data.

The common table has the partitionkey = customer partitionkey and rowkey is unique for each item.

The common table will grow to tens of millions of records per customer per yer -> that might be very large table.

Is it good to have all data in one single table or should I create customer specific tables?

Answer (score 0):

It is fine to put a lot of data in one table. There is no size limit for a table, but your account would have an overall limit of 200TB. Use good partition keys so your queries can find the entities you're looking for efficiently.